# receiving email broadcast intent in android

Tags: java, android

I am making an android application which needs the text file from whatsapp which is attached in mail on selecting email chat with a particular contact.
I want my app to be in one of the option to select from the available mail apps, which I think can be done through  receiving email broadcast or something like that. I am stuck at how to fetch that .txt file which by default would be attached to the mail so that I can read that .txt file in my app and use that .txt file further. Help me out with importing and reading that text file.

Comment: "which I figured out and can be done through receiving email broadcast" -- there is no "email broadcast" in Android.

Comment: I edited that, I meant some other broadcast receiver of that sort.

Comment: There are no broadcasts involved in the normal sending of email on Android. If you wish to write an email client that Whatsapp or other apps can work with, you need to create an activity with the appropriate `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: are you trying to intercept Intent.ACTION_SEND? Question is not very clear

Comment: I am tryong to implement this: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html but by default the whatsapp chat gets attached to mail. I want that attached file to be fetched to my app. @Shine

Comment: as stated by @CommonsWare, you should declare intent-filters inside manifest, then look for intent.getAction() and/or mime type to handle incoming content

Comment: Either your `<intent-filter>` does not match what Whatsapp is using, or Whatsapp is using some other means of identifying candidate email apps.

Comment: If you mean the "Send chat via email" whatsapp function, I doubt you'll be able to edit the behaviour, since it's defined inside whatsapp's context menu..

Comment: @Shine - but if I have more than one E-Mail app installed in my phone it asks me, which app to proceed with. So there must be a way to get my app there and fetch the file.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I haven't tried it yet with WhatsApp, I am confused how to start and how to fetch the attachment.

Comment: and it worked great.. thanks